# How to lazy load dropdown box when reaching the end in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, combobox

I have a rather simple sounding requirement. Currently, we have a Combobox which is rather inefficient because it attempts to load all the data from DB when the box is clicked. This Combobox is not typable and all I have to basically do is ensure that the data is loaded in chunks at the appropriate times i.e. when the user is at or near the end of the Combobox.

1. My initial thought was that there should be an event which I could bind to when the user scrolls towards the end of the Combobox, but no such event exists based on what I could see in event list.
2. My alternative solution is to bind on mouse wheel down event and have a method which constantly polls whether the last item is visible (although I'm not sure such property exists) and if it is, load more data.
3. My last hunch is that there should be some sort of asynchronous stream data approach to this problem which would just basically load rows without locking up the UI continuous instead of one big chunk.

Can anyone suggest anything and maybe show a quick demonstration?

Kind regards,

Vocal.

Comment: If you have a large combobox, then you should rethink of the data itself, as combobox might not the best choice for large data. So, instead of trying to load partial data on such event, I would suggest to restructure the data itself, (maybe divide it into categories ?) or add a search box for instance. just think of way to reduce the number of elements in the combobox or a different control that would fit your needs.

Comment: @BoppityBop Once in a blue moon I get to work on a monolith. It's not an everyday practice.

Comment: Either way. To implement data virtualisation in winforms is a challenge. I would avoid it at all costs